# access to list of string for push or update to list in model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

i have list of `c` and the `c` included `a` .

like this : `C1 => a1,a2,a3` , `C2=>a1,a2,a3` .

I showed them as a list of checkboxes in my page .

I need to put the `C` selected and its `a` in a list .

like this : `C1=>a1` , `C2=>a1,a3`.

i write that code but it put in list like this : `C1=>a1`,`C2=>a1`,`C2=>a3` .

Those whose `C` are the same are separate و But I need that those whose `C`

is equal is not re-created ,only their year will be updated .

**[this Smaple Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/accessmodel?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** .

and this is Model :

```
 export interface AccessModel {
    controllerNAme:string;
    actionsName:Actionsname[];
}

  export interface Actionsname {
      name:string;
  }
```

ts:

```
    onChange(event,controllerName:string,actoinName:string)
{
  this.PushAccessModel.push({
    controllerName,
    actoinName
  })
  console.log(this.PushAccessModel)
}
```

**How Can i Solve this Problem ????**

**Update**

it show me this List :

```
actoinName: "a3"
controllerName: "c1"

actoinName: "a2"
controllerName: "c1"

actoinName: "a1"
controllerName: "c1"
```

in all of object `ControllerName => C1` is Common but the are seprate

i need it show me this list :

```
controllerName: "c1"
    actoinName: "a3"
    actoinName: "a2"
    actoinName: "a1"
```

Comment: show me the list you have. also show me what you want

Comment: @GeorgeC. i put the code that here https://stackblitz.com/edit/accessmodel?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @GeorgeC. i update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did some changes to your code I hope this could help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/accessmodel-rabjub

As you can see from my code you had some types errors too so the result in console could be a little different from what you're expecting.

Anyway this is the biggest change:

```js
onChange(event,controllerName:string,actionName:string)
{
  var test = this.PushAccessModel.find(x => x.controllerName === controllerName);
  if(test){
    test.actionsName.push({name: actionName});
  }else {
    this.PushAccessModel.push({
      controllerName: controllerName,
      actionsName: [{
        name: actionName
      }]
    });
  }
  
  console.log(this.PushAccessModel)
}
```